# Braintree - create customer with Paypal details

Tags: paypal, braintree

We are studying the feasibility of using Braintree as a payment gateway for one of our client.

One of our requirement is to create a persistent customer with specific payment method/s (paypal, credit/debit etc) using
Braintree Java API.
This registered customer account will then be debited and amount transferred to the client's account as and when need arises.

We have following queries.

1. Is there any constraint/limitation as to the country to which the customer can belong to? For example, can we create a
   customer in Braintree who is a resident of India or China? Can Braintree transfer amount from a customer's account in India
   to client/merchant's account in USA and vice versa?
2. In Braintree sandbox account we can create a new customer with credit card as a payment method. How can we
   create a customer with Paypal as a payment method in sandbox?
3. I have gone through the Braintree Customer.create() Java API. Using Customer.create() API we can create a new customer
   with credit card details. But how can we create a new customer with Paypal details using API call? Where can we provide customer's
   Paypal account details while calling Customer.create()?
4. Once customer is created and payment method details verified by customer can subsequent amount transfers from customer to
   client/merchant's account happen without customer have to authorize each transaction?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you have multiple questions, I'd recommend reaching out to Braintree support at support@braintreepayments.com and reading our docs at https://developers.braintreepayments.com.

Comment: Thanks Mimarshall. Yes, I contacted Braintree email and telephonic support  and got some of my questions answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to answer your questions but I'm not Braintree ninja.

1. I think yes but there would be some charges on top of normal fees (known as currency conversion charges).
2. You can't create paypal as payment method in sandbox (I don't know the reason) but you can in production account.
3. When users choose Paypal as payment, after successful authentication a token is returned that you can save in database for future transactions (without authentication).
4. I didn't get your last question, let me answer what I understood(I guess you mean authentication again or providing details again). If customer agrees to have payment method vaulted then no, they won't have to authorize transactions in future as long as they don't cancel their payment method.

**Update:** Forgot to answer the first part of your question No. 1, as per their FAQs Braintree accepts payments from almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks MohAdnan. That was really helpful.